# mysql select value of column2 where MIN(column1)

Tags: mysql, sql, min

here is my data set and current code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9a605/3

```
| id | courseid | username |  day  | score |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |    2     |   tim    | may 5 |  85   |
| 2  |    2     |   mike   | may 6 |  86   |
| 3  |    2     |   tim    | may 7 |  82   |
| 4  |    3     |   tim    | may 8 |  80   |
| 5  |    2     |   mike   | may 9 |  79   |
| 6  |    2     |   joe    | may 10|  81   |
```

I want to select the values for each user's lowest score where courseid=2  ordered by lowest score so result should look like:

```
| mike | may 9  | 79 | 
| joe  | may 10 | 81 | 
| tim  | may 8  | 82 |
```

my current code looks like this:

```
SELECT  courseid, username, day, MIN(score) FROM    result where courseid = '2' GROUP BY username order by MIN(score) limit 10
```

my current result looks like this:

```
| mike | may 6  | 79 |
| joe  | may 10 | 81 |
| tim  | may 5  | 82 |
```

The days are wrong.

How do I get the correct day corresponding to the minimum score for that person when courseid =2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a self join on 2 conditions one with username and second with the minimum score

```
SELECT  r.courseid, r.username, r.`day`,r.score
FROM    result r
JOIN (SELECT username, MIN(score) score 
      FROM result 
      where courseid = '2'
      GROUP BY username) r1
ON(r.username = r1.username and r.score = r1.score)
order by r.score
limit 10
```

Also in your expected result tim should have date of may7

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9a605/27)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
select courseid, username, day, score
  from result x
 where score = (select min(y.score)
                  from result y
                 where y.username = x.username
                   and x.courseid = y.courseid)
   and courseid = 2
 order by score
```

**Fiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9a605/36/0